# Not able to create frame using bitmap of image view?

Tags: bitmapfactory, google-vision, android-studio-2.3, text-recognition

I am implementing the google textrecognizer which only detects frames. I am trying to build the frame using bitmap of my image in imageview, it doesnt work. But if I build frame using bitmap of drawable folder image, then it works. How can I convert the bitmap of image in a format acceptable by frame builder which textrecognize can detect.